# Modern Analogue to Whitney's Geometric Integration Theory?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, integration

Is there a more modern text that someone could suggest that covers roughly the same material as does Whitney's Geometric Integration Theory? There are a number of topics in this text that I haven't seen treated elsewhere.

Comment: Are you still curious about Whitney's book? I have read it and can compare it to books in geometric integration theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also Federer's book; here is its [amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540606564).   You may also be interested in Frank Morgan's [book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Geometric_measure_theory.html?id=fM0ISD-uaZoC) on the subject.  [These lecture notes](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFYQFjAC&url=http://www.math.ethz.ch/~lang/diab05_notes.pdf&ei=oWMkT-iZNaXb0QHH1L2CDg&usg=AFQjCNFhRrcuTHSEy-jNWhQjI8O4Ahr1uw&sig2=pV1VQooDOMX87orpVMmB7g) might also interest you.

Comment: I did not know about the book by Federer; the chapter on homological integration looks pretty interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is another book which covers all the same topics. I am only really familiar with a small portion of the book concerning the approximation of smooth manifolds with simplicial complexes. As far as I am aware, there is no other book that compares as a resource on this topic. Munkres's 'Elementary differential topology' is very good for this also, but it is hardly a more modern treatment.

I think the book by Bott and Tu "Differential forms in algebraic topology" would be an example of a more modern treatment of much of the material in the first half of Whitney's book.

I don't think there is a modern "branch" of mathematics into which Whitney's book would comfortably sit. There is geometric measure theory, and there is a book by Krantz that even has the same title as Whitney's book, which I guess you've come across if you googled that, but this has quite a different flavour from Whitney's book. It is not the same topic really, even if the same words do well to describe both.